# How to select area value from geojson using javascript

Tags: javascript, json, gis, geojson

I'm trying to right a javascript function that selects a polygon based on area value. The criterea is to select largest value if the heighest area value of a feature collection plygons is <= 20. Else, if the smalest area value a feature collection plygons is > 20, to select the smallest value. However, the results I'm getting are not the correct values.

Here is my geojson file

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "EPSG:27700" } },
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": 0,
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [514187.2405629959, 175713.65751711652],
            [514508.69769636169, 175828.21207611449],
            [514376.40576511156, 176106.02513174154],
            [513893.54021604639, 176218.47327330522],
            [513847.23804010917, 176006.80618330464],
            [514191.19706136081, 175887.74344518036],
            [514187.2405629959, 175713.65751711652]
          ]
        ]
      },
      "properties": { "FID": 0, "LSOA21CD": " ", "Area": 17.019149009300001 }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": 1,
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [514187.2405629959, 175713.65751711652],
            [514184.58246479835, 175715.76393455453],
            [514182.5480875494, 175714.1718132291],
            [513880.31102292147, 175477.63845830224],
            [514230.88464073557, 175133.6794370506],
            [514535.15608261153, 175437.95087892748],
            [514187.2405629959, 175713.65751711652]
          ]
        ]
      },
      "properties": { "FID": 1, "LSOA21CD": " ", "Area": 18.966876811500001 }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": 2,
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [514535.15608261153, 175437.95087892748],
            [514826.1983313635, 175709.14933798835],
            [514508.69769636169, 175828.21207611449],
            [514187.2405629959, 175713.65751711652],
            [514535.15608261153, 175437.95087892748]
          ]
        ]
      },
      "properties": { "FID": 2, "LSOA21CD": " ", "Area": 12.462057224500001 }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": 3,
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [514535.15608261153, 175437.95087892748],
            [515004.79243855178, 175186.59620955214],
            [515104.01138698962, 175689.30554830283],
            [514826.1983313635, 175709.14933798835],
            [514535.15608261153, 175437.95087892748]
          ]
        ]
      },
      "properties": { "FID": 3, "LSOA21CD": " ", "Area": 17.1073790847 }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": 4,
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [514696.78683049139, 175757.67865081504],
            [514826.1983313635, 175709.14933798835],
            [515104.01138698962, 175689.30554830283],
            [515381.82444261573, 176039.87916611508],
            [515025.50341344811, 176197.6531541571],
            [514696.78683049139, 175757.67865081504]
          ]
        ]
      },
      "properties": { "FID": 4, "LSOA21CD": " ", "Area": 19.0653141355 }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": 5,
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [514342.30077446159, 176500.16576545127],
            [514599.64745966345, 176386.21623817086],
            [514918.25281787943, 176786.09847348183],
            [514596.61526418198, 176941.3235537447],
            [514342.30077446159, 176500.16576545127]
          ]
        ]
      },
      "properties": { "FID": 5, "LSOA21CD": " ", "Area": 16.029109829300001 }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": 6,
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [514146.01893451158, 176159.67685941607],
            [514376.40576511156, 176106.02513174154],
            [514599.64745966624, 176386.21623817086],
            [514342.30077446159, 176500.16576545127],
            [514146.01893451158, 176159.67685941607]
          ]
        ]
      },
      "properties": { "FID": 6, "LSOA21CD": " ", "Area": 9.3259778883800006 }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": 7,
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [514342.30077446159, 176500.16576545127],
            [514052.29053354729, 176628.57826018333],
            [514051.82526298054, 176627.37631121837],
            [513893.54021604639, 176218.47327330522],
            [514146.01893451158, 176159.67685941607],
            [514342.30077446159, 176500.16576545127]
          ]
        ]
      },
      "properties": { "FID": 7, "LSOA21CD": " ", "Area": 11.841352065100001 }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": 8,
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [513976.92131792102, 175961.91581790708],
            [513847.23804010917, 176006.80618330464],
            [513443.74764979444, 175590.08659986407],
            [513619.21886995155, 175544.88946740143],
            [513976.92131792102, 175961.91581790708]
          ]
        ]
      },
      "properties": { "FID": 8, "LSOA21CD": " ", "Area": 8.0748820024299999 }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": 9,
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [513619.21886995155, 175544.88946740143],
            [513880.31102292147, 175477.63845830224],
            [514182.5480875494, 175714.1718132291],
            [514184.58246479835, 175715.76393455453],
            [514187.2405629959, 175713.65751711652],
            [514191.19706136081, 175887.74344518036],
            [513976.92131792102, 175961.91581790708],
            [513619.21886995155, 175544.88946740143]
          ]
        ]
      },
      "properties": { "FID": 9, "LSOA21CD": " ", "Area": 14.7548642798 }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": 10,
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [513619.21886995155, 175544.88946740143],
            [513443.74764979444, 175590.08659986407],
            [513284.99733229354, 175411.49249267764],
            [513532.47008709889, 175269.49992844649],
            [513619.21886995155, 175544.88946740143]
          ]
        ]
      },
      "properties": { "FID": 10, "LSOA21CD": " ", "Area": 5.9491137500200004 }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": 11,
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [514731.50091127306, 174880.67981645837],
            [514846.04212105088, 174822.79339861497],
            [515004.79243855178, 175186.59620955214],
            [514906.41315287724, 175239.24991174601],
            [514731.50091127306, 174880.67981645837]
          ]
        ]
      },
      "properties": { "FID": 11, "LSOA21CD": " ", "Area": 4.7672774107500002 }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": 12,
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [514906.41315287724, 175239.24991174601],
            [514535.15608261153, 175437.95087892748],
            [514230.88464073557, 175133.6794370506],
            [514731.50091127306, 174880.67981645837],
            [514906.41315287724, 175239.24991174601]
          ]
        ]
      },
      "properties": { "FID": 12, "LSOA21CD": " ", "Area": 19.859035422800002 }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": 13,
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [514917.07963621151, 176245.66169233806],
            [515025.50341344532, 176197.6531541571],
            [515320.21211783122, 176592.10942002572],
            [515205.25406012032, 176647.58917831443],
            [514917.07963621151, 176245.66169233806]
          ]
        ]
      },
      "properties": { "FID": 13, "LSOA21CD": " ", "Area": 5.9554811448900002 }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": 14,
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [515205.25406012032, 176647.58917831443],
            [514918.25281787943, 176786.09847348183],
            [514599.64745966345, 176386.21623817086],
            [514917.07963621151, 176245.66169233806],
            [515205.25406012032, 176647.58917831443]
          ]
        ]
      },
      "properties": { "FID": 14, "LSOA21CD": " ", "Area": 16.349272192400001 }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": 15,
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [514594.66286209505, 175795.97513896786],
            [514696.78683049139, 175757.67865081504],
            [515025.50341344811, 176197.6531541571],
            [514917.07963621151, 176245.66169233806],
            [514594.66286209505, 175795.97513896786]
          ]
        ]
      },
      "properties": { "FID": 15, "LSOA21CD": " ", "Area": 6.0878052849299999 }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": 16,
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [514917.07963621151, 176245.66169233806],
            [514599.64745966624, 176386.21623817086],
            [514376.40576511156, 176106.02513174154],
            [514508.69769636169, 175828.21207611449],
            [514594.66286209505, 175795.97513896786],
            [514917.07963621151, 176245.66169233806]
          ]
        ]
      },
      "properties": { "FID": 16, "LSOA21CD": " ", "Area": 16.9024733312 }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": 17,
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [514040.11921087652, 176716.00784859248],
            [514051.82526298054, 176627.37631121837],
            [514052.29053354729, 176628.57826018333],
            [514342.30077446159, 176500.16576545127],
            [514596.61526418198, 176941.3235537447],
            [514294.3159738658, 177087.21581993997],
            [514040.11921087652, 176716.00784859248]
          ]
        ]
      },
      "properties": { "FID": 17, "LSOA21CD": " ", "Area": 18.067530070499998 }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": 18,
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [515631.83968934324, 176441.71524421126],
            [515320.21211783122, 176592.10942002572],
            [515025.50341344532, 176197.6531541571],
            [515381.82444261573, 176039.87916611508],
            [515640.5562169617, 176267.38469183631],
            [515631.83968934324, 176441.71524421126]
          ]
        ]
      },
      "properties": { "FID": 18, "LSOA21CD": " ", "Area": 19.848118984599999 }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": 19,
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [514154.5027258927, 175031.8368839249],
            [514230.88464073557, 175133.6794370506],
            [513880.31102292147, 175477.63845830224],
            [513619.21886995155, 175544.88946740143],
            [513532.47008709889, 175269.49992844649],
            [513897.89380010497, 175059.83058492094],
            [514154.5027258927, 175031.8368839249]
          ]
        ]
      },
      "properties": { "FID": 19, "LSOA21CD": " ", "Area": 19.771145470800001 }
    }
  ]
}
```

And here is the javascript function that I wrote.

```
const data = require("./area.json");

console.log(
  data.features.reduce((sampleArea, selectedArea) => {
    if (sampleArea[selectedArea.properties.Area] <= 20) {
      Math.max(sampleArea[selectedArea.properties.Area]);
    } else Math.min(sampleArea[selectedArea.properties.Area]);
    return selectedArea.properties.Area;
  }, {})
);
```

The answer I got is

`PS E:\polygons\test> node script.js 19.7711454708`

However the correct answer is

`19.859035422800002`

I have tried with a different geojson data, where the smallest area is `23.884209`, but I got `35.5510673211`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be easier to create an array of area values by [`mapping`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over the features, and then using [`Math.min`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min) and [`Math.max`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) on that array to get the min/max values.

```js
const data={type:"FeatureCollection",crs:{type:"name",properties:{name:"EPSG:27700"}},features:[{type:"Feature",id:0,geometry:{type:"Polygon",coordinates:[[[514187.2405629959,175713.65751711652],[514508.6976963617,175828.2120761145],[514376.40576511156,176106.02513174154],[513893.5402160464,176218.47327330522],[513847.23804010917,176006.80618330464],[514191.1970613608,175887.74344518036],[514187.2405629959,175713.65751711652]]]},properties:{FID:0,LSOA21CD:" ",Area:17.0191490093}},{type:"Feature",id:1,geometry:{type:"Polygon",coordinates:[[[514187.2405629959,175713.65751711652],[514184.58246479835,175715.76393455453],[514182.5480875494,175714.1718132291],[513880.31102292147,175477.63845830224],[514230.8846407356,175133.6794370506],[514535.15608261153,175437.95087892748],[514187.2405629959,175713.65751711652]]]},properties:{FID:1,LSOA21CD:" ",Area:18.9668768115}},{type:"Feature",id:2,geometry:{type:"Polygon",coordinates:[[[514535.15608261153,175437.95087892748],[514826.1983313635,175709.14933798835],[514508.6976963617,175828.2120761145],[514187.2405629959,175713.65751711652],[514535.15608261153,175437.95087892748]]]},properties:{FID:2,LSOA21CD:" ",Area:12.4620572245}},{type:"Feature",id:3,geometry:{type:"Polygon",coordinates:[[[514535.15608261153,175437.95087892748],[515004.7924385518,175186.59620955214],[515104.0113869896,175689.30554830283],[514826.1983313635,175709.14933798835],[514535.15608261153,175437.95087892748]]]},properties:{FID:3,LSOA21CD:" ",Area:17.1073790847}},{type:"Feature",id:4,geometry:{type:"Polygon",coordinates:[[[514696.7868304914,175757.67865081504],[514826.1983313635,175709.14933798835],[515104.0113869896,175689.30554830283],[515381.82444261573,176039.87916611508],[515025.5034134481,176197.6531541571],[514696.7868304914,175757.67865081504]]]},properties:{FID:4,LSOA21CD:" ",Area:19.0653141355}},{type:"Feature",id:5,geometry:{type:"Polygon",coordinates:[[[514342.3007744616,176500.16576545127],[514599.64745966345,176386.21623817086],[514918.25281787943,176786.09847348183],[514596.615264182,176941.3235537447],[514342.3007744616,176500.16576545127]]]},properties:{FID:5,LSOA21CD:" ",Area:16.0291098293}},{type:"Feature",id:6,geometry:{type:"Polygon",coordinates:[[[514146.0189345116,176159.67685941607],[514376.40576511156,176106.02513174154],[514599.64745966624,176386.21623817086],[514342.3007744616,176500.16576545127],[514146.0189345116,176159.67685941607]]]},properties:{FID:6,LSOA21CD:" ",Area:9.32597788838}},{type:"Feature",id:7,geometry:{type:"Polygon",coordinates:[[[514342.3007744616,176500.16576545127],[514052.2905335473,176628.57826018333],[514051.82526298054,176627.37631121837],[513893.5402160464,176218.47327330522],[514146.0189345116,176159.67685941607],[514342.3007744616,176500.16576545127]]]},properties:{FID:7,LSOA21CD:" ",Area:11.8413520651}},{type:"Feature",id:8,geometry:{type:"Polygon",coordinates:[[[513976.921317921,175961.91581790708],[513847.23804010917,176006.80618330464],[513443.74764979444,175590.08659986407],[513619.21886995155,175544.88946740143],[513976.921317921,175961.91581790708]]]},properties:{FID:8,LSOA21CD:" ",Area:8.07488200243}},{type:"Feature",id:9,geometry:{type:"Polygon",coordinates:[[[513619.21886995155,175544.88946740143],[513880.31102292147,175477.63845830224],[514182.5480875494,175714.1718132291],[514184.58246479835,175715.76393455453],[514187.2405629959,175713.65751711652],[514191.1970613608,175887.74344518036],[513976.921317921,175961.91581790708],[513619.21886995155,175544.88946740143]]]},properties:{FID:9,LSOA21CD:" ",Area:14.7548642798}},{type:"Feature",id:10,geometry:{type:"Polygon",coordinates:[[[513619.21886995155,175544.88946740143],[513443.74764979444,175590.08659986407],[513284.99733229354,175411.49249267764],[513532.4700870989,175269.4999284465],[513619.21886995155,175544.88946740143]]]},properties:{FID:10,LSOA21CD:" ",Area:5.94911375002}},{type:"Feature",id:11,geometry:{type:"Polygon",coordinates:[[[514731.50091127306,174880.67981645837],[514846.0421210509,174822.79339861497],[515004.7924385518,175186.59620955214],[514906.41315287724,175239.249911746],[514731.50091127306,174880.67981645837]]]},properties:{FID:11,LSOA21CD:" ",Area:4.76727741075}},{type:"Feature",id:12,geometry:{type:"Polygon",coordinates:[[[514906.41315287724,175239.249911746],[514535.15608261153,175437.95087892748],[514230.8846407356,175133.6794370506],[514731.50091127306,174880.67981645837],[514906.41315287724,175239.249911746]]]},properties:{FID:12,LSOA21CD:" ",Area:19.8590354228}},{type:"Feature",id:13,geometry:{type:"Polygon",coordinates:[[[514917.0796362115,176245.66169233806],[515025.5034134453,176197.6531541571],[515320.2121178312,176592.10942002572],[515205.2540601203,176647.58917831443],[514917.0796362115,176245.66169233806]]]},properties:{FID:13,LSOA21CD:" ",Area:5.95548114489}},{type:"Feature",id:14,geometry:{type:"Polygon",coordinates:[[[515205.2540601203,176647.58917831443],[514918.25281787943,176786.09847348183],[514599.64745966345,176386.21623817086],[514917.0796362115,176245.66169233806],[515205.2540601203,176647.58917831443]]]},properties:{FID:14,LSOA21CD:" ",Area:16.3492721924}},{type:"Feature",id:15,geometry:{type:"Polygon",coordinates:[[[514594.66286209505,175795.97513896786],[514696.7868304914,175757.67865081504],[515025.5034134481,176197.6531541571],[514917.0796362115,176245.66169233806],[514594.66286209505,175795.97513896786]]]},properties:{FID:15,LSOA21CD:" ",Area:6.08780528493}},{type:"Feature",id:16,geometry:{type:"Polygon",coordinates:[[[514917.0796362115,176245.66169233806],[514599.64745966624,176386.21623817086],[514376.40576511156,176106.02513174154],[514508.6976963617,175828.2120761145],[514594.66286209505,175795.97513896786],[514917.0796362115,176245.66169233806]]]},properties:{FID:16,LSOA21CD:" ",Area:16.9024733312}},{type:"Feature",id:17,geometry:{type:"Polygon",coordinates:[[[514040.1192108765,176716.00784859248],[514051.82526298054,176627.37631121837],[514052.2905335473,176628.57826018333],[514342.3007744616,176500.16576545127],[514596.615264182,176941.3235537447],[514294.3159738658,177087.21581993997],[514040.1192108765,176716.00784859248]]]},properties:{FID:17,LSOA21CD:" ",Area:18.0675300705}},{type:"Feature",id:18,geometry:{type:"Polygon",coordinates:[[[515631.83968934324,176441.71524421126],[515320.2121178312,176592.10942002572],[515025.5034134453,176197.6531541571],[515381.82444261573,176039.87916611508],[515640.5562169617,176267.3846918363],[515631.83968934324,176441.71524421126]]]},properties:{FID:18,LSOA21CD:" ",Area:19.8481189846}},{type:"Feature",id:19,geometry:{type:"Polygon",coordinates:[[[514154.5027258927,175031.8368839249],[514230.8846407356,175133.6794370506],[513880.31102292147,175477.63845830224],[513619.21886995155,175544.88946740143],[513532.4700870989,175269.4999284465],[513897.89380010497,175059.83058492094],[514154.5027258927,175031.8368839249]]]},properties:{FID:19,LSOA21CD:" ",Area:19.7711454708}}]};

const areas = data.features.map(feature => feature.properties.Area);
const min = Math.min(...areas);
const max = Math.max(...areas);

if (max <= 20) console.log(max);
if (min > 20) console.log(min);
```